# Circular Ranking implementation in Javascript

Tags: javascript, ranking

Is there a way in javascript to establish a non-linear ranking hierarchy, something like a>b>c>a?

where something like:

```
> a>b
true
> b>c
true
> c>a
true
```

can always be consistent?

Comment: if `a` is bigger than `b` and `b` is bigger than `c` how is `c` bigger than `a`?

Comment: "always be constant"  What does this mean?

Comment: You can't redefine `>` operator in javascript.

Comment: that was a little vague on my part, changed constant to consistent

Comment: Is your ordering always cyclic? That is, given a set of elements do all the elements of the set always form a single cycle wherein each element always has a predecessor and a successor?

Comment: @Aadit M Shah that is correct, I was wondering about using something like a circular queue consisting of [0,1,2] and rotating it based on what the preceding object was but I'm still trying to figure out if that is a dead end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're referring to is a [cyclic order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_order). For example, consider the months of a year:

```
                       +----> March -----+
                       |                 |
                       |                 v
             +----> February           April -----+
             |                                    |
             |                                    v
   +----> January                                May -----+
   |                                                      |
   |                                                      v
December                                                 June
   ^                                                      |
   |                                                      |
   +----- November                              July <----+
             ^                                    |
             |                                    |
             +----- October           August <----+
                       ^                 |
                       |                 |
                       +--- September <--+
```

In a cyclic order it doesn't make sense to say things like “January comes before March” because it doesn't always come before March. However, it does make sense to say things like “after August, January comes before March” and “after February, March comes before January”.

To put it in programming terms:

```js
after(August, January, March);   // true
after(February, March, January); // true
```

There's also a little hack which'll allow you to write code like this:

```js
after(August),   January < March; // true
after(February), January > March; // true
```

Here's how to make it work:

```js
const [ March
      , April
      , May
      , June
      , July
      , August
      , September
      , October
      , November
      , December
      , January
      , February ] = cycle();

console.log((after(August),   January < March)); // true
console.log((after(February), January > March)); // true

function* cycle(n = 1, j = 0) {
    for (let i = 0; true; i++, n++) {
        yield {
            valueOf: () => (i + j) % n,
            get after() { j = n - i; }
        };
    }
}

function after(x) {
    return x.after;
}
```

On an interesting side note, did you know that March was the first month of the Roman calendar? Think about it:

1. March marks the beginning of Spring, the season of new life. Hence, the beginning of the year coincides with the beginning of new life.
2. If March is the first month then September, October, November and December are the 7th, 8th, 9th and 10th month respectively. Hence, they are called September (septa for 7), October (octa for 8), November (nona for 9) and December (deca for 10).

Anyway, hope that helped.

Comment: This is a lot to digest for now Aadit, but I understand the gist of it. Thank you very much for putting the effort into writing this!

Answer (score 1):

You can create objects which alter themselves on conversion:

```js
let x = { valueOf: () => this.v = ~this.v };
console.log(x < x);

let a = b = c = x;
console.log(a < b && b < c && c < a);
```

It is impossible for non-changing objects, as Number with the comparison operator is transitive.

Notes: [valueOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/valueOf) is used in the implicit conversion to Number by `<`. `~this.v` is just a trick to shorten the initialization in this case, `~undefined === -1`. Afterwards `this.v` alternates between `-1` and `0`.

This has the issue that it inverts when `valueOf` is being called only once. An alternative would be to use an ever-increasing counter. I do not think that it is possible to detect, whether the `valueOf` call comes from a comparison or not.

```js
let counter = 0;
let x = { valueOf: () => counter++ };
console.log(x < x);

let a = b = c = x;
console.log(a < b && b < c && c < a);
console.log(x.valueOf());
console.log(a < b && b < c && c < a);
```

Comment: unfortunately this won't let the comparison always be constant

Comment: @user3080953 Yes, I was focusing more on the general concept. I added a version which should be more robust at the end, however, all these are quite hacky. I would suggest just using a function instead of the operator, but that was not the question. If javascript had operator overloading, it would be easier.